Can I detect (at compile time) whether I'm in an extern "C" {} block?
Say I have a C header file a.h
Any C++ header file, say a.hpp that #includes a.h, should do so in an extern "C" block.
So I have some header files that are common between our C++ code and C code, and I want all the C++ code to #include a wrapper plus helpers version.
For example, if I have "a.h", I also have a "a.hpp" that #includes a.h in an extern "C" block and adds some relevant C++ helper code.
Thus I want all C++ code to #include "a.hpp" NOT "a.h".
Of course, humans being human, sometimes we forget.
The usual signal that something like that has happened is at link time, as the function name declarations are mangled and hence the link fails.
So I want something that I can put in a.h, will fail at compile time, if a.h is being  compiled by a C++ compiler, but NOT in an extern "C" block.
The first part of that is easy...
Just use #ifdef __cplusplus
How do I do the second part, namely detect at compile time whether I'm in a extern "C" block?

You can avoid the need for this entirely, by making a.h have #ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" { ... and similar for closing brace.  Then any other cpp file can just include it without worry

"So I want something that I can put in a.h, will fail at compile time, if a.h is being compiled by a C++ compiler, but NOT in an extern "C" block." -- Is this really what you want, or might you want something that you can put in a.h that will fail at compile time if a.h is being compiled by a C++ compiler, but NOT included by a.hpp?

I don't see why you need to consider including "a.h" in C++ to be an error.

sounds like XY problem to me

Not sure, if this is necessary but you could define a macro in a.hpp (before the #include "a.h") and check whether it is defined in a.h wrapped in #ifdef __cplusplus (so that it doesn't affect the C compiler). If the check fails you could use #error to force a compiler error. (This is aside of the concerns whether it's worth all the trickery...)

"might you want something that you can put in a.h that will fail at compile time if a.h is being compiled by a C++ compiler, but NOT included by a.hpp? – JaMiT" Yup, that will work, I'll probably do that.

If you cannot modify a.h, the question is moot.
If you can modify a.h, it makes no sense to do something to detect wrong usage. Instead, you should make wrong usage impossible as M.M said:
// in a.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
// main content here
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

Then you include a.h and it just works.

If you cannot modify a.h, the question is moot. well, it can always be wrapped in an extra header file and the latter can be exposed to API's consumers. If it's a good practice or not is another topic.

Except I really want them to #include the a.hpp as it supplies additional related facilities implemented in C++, and hopefully at some point in the future, all over a.h is moved into a.hpp and a.h is deleted. Doing it this way, at that point I don't have to change any client files.

@JohnCarter you could have a.hpp do #define THIS_IS_A_HPP , and then in a.h, have #if (defined __cplusplus && !defined THIS_IS_A_HPP) #error ...  . Could even use the same token for the a.hpp header guard

There is no difference init being  outside or insde of header file for compiler.Everything done before compilation and it reads a complete file.
canonical way to do it IN header file (what standard libraries often do).
//  A new a.h

#ifdef __cplusplus
#  define EXTERN_DECL extern "C"
#  define EXTERN_SPACE_BEGIN  EXTERN_DECL  {
#  define EXTERN_SPACE_END }
#else 
#  define EXTERN_DECL extern
#  define EXTERN_SPACE_BEGIN 
#  define EXTERN_SPACE_END 
#endif

EXTERN_SPACE_BEGIN
#include "lib_includes/library_a/a.h"
EXTERN_SPACE_END 

If your header file is third party, se itfrom some private location lib_includes not added to includes and have own header wrapped around it.
Note, practcally all POSIX headers do something like this with macro definitions to be compatible with C and C++ at same time.

Except the question isn't whether I can detect whether I'm in a header file or not. The question is can I detect whether I'm in an extern "C" block or not.

@JohnCarter you can't detect at preprocessing time because the block doesn't exist for preprocessor. And there is no standard way to do that, because the block is nothing but a shorthand of adding extern "C" to each function and variable declaration in it, which changes their  internal name and comes into play at late compiling andlinking stages, it's not stateful. Only way to detect is to detect that you're in particular file or section of file,using your own rigid structure

The suggestions provided by @JaMit and @Scheff's Cat, while not exactly the answer to the question, will work for the problem at hand (the question being 'how do you detect if you're in an extern "C" block').

define a macro in a.hpp (before the #include "a.h") and check whether
it is defined in a.h wrapped in #ifdef __cplusplus (so that it doesn't
affect the C compiler). If the check fails you could use #error to
force a compiler error.

